# Unable to reach controller ActionResult from javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

**EDIT 2**
I was able to solve the problem. There was nothing wrong with the Javascript or Controller code. The problem came from a .dll file. In the controller method I build a new TextInfo object from the TextModel object. The TextInfo object comes from a .dll that's build from the API. This .dll however had multiple instances with different build dates in the File System. Seems like the old version wasn't removed properly but it was the one the compiler used. This created a 500 Internal Server Error telling me that a Method wasn't available.

**EDIT 1**
*I'm fairly certain my problem stems from a property in my model not being set correctly but I'm not sure why. I had 1 instance where I was able to debug though furhter into the code but I'm clueless as to why or how that happened. Will update later once I find more answers.*

I am having trouble accessing the controller action from my ajax call and it honestly makes no sense to me as to why I'm unable to start the code. The issue seems to be with the CurrentPageNumber. When I comment out this variable from both c# and javascript, I am able to hit the breakpoint in the controller. But when I uncomment that variable I can't hit the breakpoint. The error I'm getting is 500 Internal Server Error. To me that sounds like the JSON keys aren't the same as the Controller parameters, but as you can see below that isn't the case (unless if I turned blind). Any idea what the problem could be? Prehaps I'm looking in the wrong direction?

**tl;dr Controller ActionResult not started when CurrentPageNumber is in the parameter and key list (uncommented), but it does start when it isn't (commented out).**

I am trying to reach the following ActionResult.

```
public ActionResult SavePageInfo(List<TextModel> TextObjects, string ImageSource, int CurrentPageNumber)
```

I do this with the help of the following AJAX call

```
var json = JSON.stringify({ TextObjects: textObjects, ImageSource: imageSource, CurrentPageNumber: pageNumber });

$.ajax({
    url: "/NextprintPhotobook/SavePageInfo",
    type: "POST",
    data: json,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.message);
        alert(data.message);
    }
})
```

The JSON that's produced looks like this (as you can see all values are set):

> "{"TextObjects":[{"text":"Test","x":50,"y":50,"fillColor":"#77DD44","fontFamily":"arial","fontStyle":"normal","fontSize":"18pt","fontWeight":"normal","textAlignment":"start","angle":0}],
>   "ImageSource":"http://localhost:22223/api/file/getfile?name=04.jpg&collectionId=4103&version=1&size=original",
>   "CurrentPageNumber":1}"

TextModel is as follows:

```
public class TextModel
{
    public string text
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public int x
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public int y
    {
        get; set;
    }
    // Same properties as in the JSON. 
}
```

Comment: got a feeling it may have to do with mvc and mapping to your list param... they need to be indexed soda speak.. try looking into this... i could be wrong.... mvc adds prefex names to lists with index's so that it knows how to map to lists..

Comment: are you sure your url is correct?  try with the '/' in the begining NextprintPhotobook/SavePageInfo

Comment: Use `@Html.ActionLink()` instead of text url.

Comment: @Seabizkit The tl;dr says that the code works if the CurrentPageNumber is commented out. Doesn't that tell us that the indexing of the list is done correctly?

Comment: The URL is correct. I've been able to hit the first line in the controller function as explained in the text.

Comment: Use your browser tools (Network tab) to inspect the response - it will give you the details of the error

Comment: @DaBazz totally get you, and agree.. i'm not sure if you are describing it 100% tho....as then it would be hard to understand why it is not working.... what is the 500 error message. like the actual message, which key is it complaining about.

Comment: have you tried just using a different variable name on both sides. I know it doesn't make sense... just ruling out

Comment: @StephenMuecke It seems like it errors on setting a property of TextModel. But I'm not sure why (setWeight not found). I have had a weird interaction while debugging though where I did hit the breakpoint in the controller code that I was looking for (which means the setWeight was found in this instance?). I'll comment again once I found the problem later today.

Comment: Resolved the problem. It came from a malicious .dll file that wasn't deleted after the project was cleaned/(re)build. More info in original post.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not using a single object as parameter (a wrapper class for all those params)? (usually this is how it is done, unless you want to add some params in the query string also)

Comment: ill let someone else mark this down. as i want to be neutral, but how does this solve or help his problem

Answer (score 0):

this is not the answer... well (i just want to put it here so its easier to read)

try this:

```
var data = {
    TextObjects: JSON.stringify(textObjects),
    ImageSource: imageSource
    CurrentPageNumber: pageNumber
}

$.ajax({
    url: "/NextprintPhotobook/SavePageInfo",
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (res) {
        console.log(res.message);
        alert(res.message);
    }
});
```

Comment: my only problem with this is im sure JSON.stringify(textObjects) will not be in the MVC controller auto-mapping format for collections